# Android: Is there an idea to lock (block) only certain activity?

Tags: android, android-security

Android: I don't want to block an entire app (which AppLock does), but I just want to block a certain activity from it. What ideas or app are there?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to create a activity which is used to login. Then when you want lock any activity, just call the login activity first.

Comment: Sorry I didn't ask my question well. I want to block an activity from another software package, not an activity from my own software package. What AppLock does is request a password to enter the main activity of an app. I want to apply this not to all the program but only to a certain activity of it.

Comment: @MED i'm not clear about what your app do but you can set `intent-filter` for login activity. After that depend on `intent.data` you recived in login activity and check user login info, just start that certain activity you want from login activity.